# method is performing incorrect calculations on double argument

Tags: java, math

firstly, im sorry if this is a trivial question. I am a beginner and have been stuck on this for hours.

Below I have tried to create a unitizer method which has a series of if else statements. They are written in descending order, each time checking if a value can be divided by a given number, and if so, performing a division, rounding the value and adding an appropriate unit to the result.

in this question I have attempted to remove all unnecessary code, thus what i am presenting here is only a fragment of the unitizer method.

**why is the unitizer method outputting values in hours, when the value should be in seconds?**

For clarification, the expected value is ~ 4 seconds.

```
public class simplified 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

            int i = 5;
            double n = Math.pow(2, (double) i);
            System.out.println(a6(n)); // correctly displays the expected value.
            System.out.println(unitizer(a6(n)));

        }

        public static double a6 (double n)
        {
            return Math.pow(2, n); // this value is in nanoseconds.
        }

        public static String unitizer (double x)
        {
            String time = "";

            if (x/(60*60*1000*1000*1000) >= 1) 
            {
                x = Math.round(x/(60*60*1000*1000*1000) * 100.0) / 100.0;
                time = x + "hr ";
            }

            return time;
        }   

}
```

console output:

```
4.294967296E9
5.25hr
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to print seconds if nowhere in your code it says seconds. You have written "hr", thus it will print "hr". Why do you divide by 60*60 and expect 4? if you remove 60*60 you should get 4.29

Comment: @MartinW The problem is, I never reach that section of my if-else statement. One of the omissions of this question is the if else part which checks if the argument / 1000*1000*1000 is >= 1, which isnt reached, so the code isnt able to evaluate the argument as seconds. That part comes later. In short, the if-condition shouldn't be evaluating as true here.

Comment: @Izruo I don't understand. There shouldn't be an int here, everything before the String is supposed to be a double. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Izruo thanks, I didn't know that. Can you elaborate why you included the character L? does that refer to long? Could I otherwise write the expression 60*... in such a way that is interpreted as a double? perhaps by including a decimal and following zero? EDIT: I presume the answer to that question is just to write (double). I will revisit the code.

Comment: Excellent. I will revisit the code. If it works, you can repost the comment as an answer and i will approve it for this question.

EDIT: @Izruo if you want to repost your comment as an answer, I will gladly approve it. Thanks, you have solved my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162654/discussion-between-izruo-and-oscar-r).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `int` overflow at the expression `60*60*1000*1000*1000`. This means, that the actual result `3,600,000,000,000` is too large to be stored as an `int` value and is therefore 'reduced' (`mod 2^31`) to `817,405,952`.

---

This can be fixed by evaluating said expression in a 'larger' arithmetic, e.g. `long`. There is a nice little modifier, that will force exactly that:

```
60L*60*1000*1000*1000
  ^
```

In particular, it hints the compiler to interpret the preceding literal `60` as a `long` value and in consequence the whole calculation will be done in `long` arithmetic.
This modifier is by the way case-insensitive; however I prefer an upper-case `L`, because the lower-case letter `l` can easily be mistaken by the number `1`.

With this change, the code will not enter the `if`-statement, because the value `x` is not larger than one hour. Most probably the omitted code of `unitizer` will deal with this case.

---

On a last side note, `java` has an in-built [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum, which can do these conversions, too. However, it does so in `long` arithmetic and not in `double` arithmetic as it is required for this specific question.